# Смена запроса при нажатии кнопок Wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Есть функция:

```
function get_bulk_actions() {
  return array(1 => 'Все мероприятия', 2 => 'Действующие');
}
```

Которая выводит кнопки в мою кастомную таблицу wp внутри админ панели.
Как сделать/задействовать их, чтобы при нажатии данных кнопок, менялся запрос в функции get_data():

```
function get_data(){
global $wpdb;
// Все мероприятия
   $evpl_places->query['join'][] = "INNER JOIN ".WP_PREFIX."evpl_orders AS orders ON places.order_id=orders.order_id";
// Действующие
   $evpl_places->query['join'][] = "INNER JOIN ".WP_PREFIX."evpl_orders AS orders ON places.order_id=orders.order_id INNER JOIN Event AS event ON event.event_id=places.event_id";
}
```

Я заменил первую функцию:

```
function get_bulk_actions() { 
echo $kn = '<form method="post"><input type="submit" name="insert" value="Все"><input type="submit" name="select" value="Действующие" ></form>'; 
}
```

А вторую функцию обновил на:

```
if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
  $evpl_places->query['join'][] = "INNER JOIN ".WP_PREFIX."evpl_orders AS orders ON places.order_id=orders.order_id"; 
}
if(isset($_GET['select'])){ 
  $evpl_places->query['join'][] = "INNER JOIN ".WP_PREFIX."evpl_orders AS orders ON places.order_id=orders.order_id INNER JOIN Event AS event ON event.event_id=places.event_id"; 
}
```

Но теперь запрос вообще не отправляется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая функция с кнопками у меня получилось такая:

```
    function get_bulk_actions() {
    echo $all_events =  '<form method="POST" action="get_data()"><input type="submit" name="insert" value="Все"></form>';
    }
```

В ней я решил оставить только одну кнопку.
А вторая функция:

```
    function get_data(){
    global $wpdb;
    if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
    $request_all_events= $evpl_places->query['join'][] = "INNER JOIN ".WP_PREFIX."evpl_orders AS orders ON places.order_id=orders.order_id";
    }else{
    $request_all_events= $evpl_places->query['join'][] = "INNER JOIN ".WP_PREFIX."evpl_orders AS orders ON places.order_id=orders.order_id INNER JOIN Event AS event ON event.event_id=places.event_id";
    }
```

Возможно это сделано криво, но на данный момент, главное работает)